# Updating property inside a nested array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array, and I wanted to update the selected frameId template inside a specific object using the id 
I tried this, but if I select frameId = 1 for example, all frameId 1 template is edited, I want only the id that is selected.

```
 sizes.map(size => {
      if(size.id === id){
        size.frames.map(frame => {
          if(frame.frameId === frameId){
            frame.template = {test: '101'}
          }
          return frame
        })
      }
      return size
    })
```

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Mrec',
      frames: [
        {
          frameId: 1,
          template: {},
          img: [],
        },
        {
          frameId: 2,
          template: {},
          img: [],
        },
      ],
      active: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Leaderboard',
      frames: [
        {
          frameId: 1,
          template: {},
          img: [],
        },
        {
          frameId: 2,
          template: {},
          img: [],
        },
      ],
      active: false
    }
]
```

Comment: I think you have a typo `if(frame.id === frameId)` should be `if(frame.frameId === frameId)`. Change that and it should  work

Comment: @ptothep tnx bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think right mehtod is this. (#edit: It works on snippet)

```js
var id = 1,
frameId=2;
var sizes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Mrec',
      frames: [
        {
          frameId: 1,
          template: {},
          img: [],
        },
        {
          frameId: 2,
          template: {},
          img: [],
        },
      ],
      active: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Leaderboard',
      frames: [
        {
          frameId: 1,
          template: {},
          img: [],
        },
        {
          frameId: 2,
          template: {},
          img: [],
        },
      ],
      active: false
    }
]

sizes.map(size => {
        let frames;
        if (size.id === id) {
            frames = size.frames.map(frame => {
                if (frame.frameId === frameId) {
                    frame.template = { test: '101' }
                }
                return frame;
            })
        } else {
            frames = size.frames;
        }
        return {...size,frames}
    })
document.write(JSON.stringify(sizes))
```

Comment: still the same output, every frameId is populated

Comment: Would you run the snippet